# Fatal Error 0x80096010 installing Windows Essentials 2012 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, installation, windows-10, windows-movie-maker

I am trying to install **Windows Essentials 2012** on my **Windows 10** PC. Firstly I tried installing online but it was getting stuck on 62% every time. Then I downloaded offline installation package. I got a **Fatal Error** before installation could start. I want Windows Movie Maker from the essentials. Please help me out. Thanks in advance!

Here's the screenshot:

[image: Windows Essentials 2012 Installation Screenshot]

Comment: 0x80096010 means **TRUST_E_BAD_DIGEST - The digital signature of the object did not verify** looks like the digital signature expired.

Comment: what to do now?